# Why do I have to use ld to link my binary

Tags: linux, nasm, elf

I'm doing a little "Hello World" program in NASM to run on my Ubuntu machine (uname -a output included below):

```
 $uname -a
Linux desk069 4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:24:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Now after saving this to a file, I have to run

```
nasm -f elf64 ./test. ./test.nasm -o test.o
ld -o test test.o -m elf_x86_64
```

In order for my code to work. Attempting to run `test.o` gives me

```
bash: ./test.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

and attempting to make NASM generate a bin file gives me:

```
$nasm -f bin ./test.nasm -o test.bin
$chmod +x ./test.bin
$./test.bin
bash: ./test.bin: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

My question is, I'm not using any libraries. Why do I have to use the linker ld? What exactly is wrong with the bin file? Can I do something to make it run without `ld`?

My code is included below.

```
section .text
    global _start

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa 
len equ $- msg 

section .text

_start:

    mov edx, len 
    mov ecx, msg 
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

Comment: You don't run object files. when you do `ld -o test test.o -m elf_x86_64` this creates an ELF executable from `test.o` and outputs it as an ELF executable called `test`. To run it you use `./test` . You also don't run `bin` files as ELF executables. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: What about `nasm -f bin ./test.nasm -o test.bin`? Surely if I told NASM to give me binary, it must give me a binary?

Comment: It will generate a binary but Linux's loader doesn't run bin files. It will run ELF executables. Unless your bin file happened to be designed to look like an ELF executable it won't run. The linker takes object files and produces executables that can be loaded by the Linux loader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do I have to use the linker ld?

You don't have to use `ld`, but it's much easier to use it than not (see below).

> What exactly is wrong with the bin file?

Nothing in the `.bin` file tells the OS *how* to load and run it.

At what address should the OS map this file into memory? Where should it set the `RIP` register to start executing it?

When you create a program which will run on a "bare metal" system, you can arrange for this program to be loaded at exactly the processor reset address, and the processor will start fetching and executing instructions from that address when it is powered on.

But you aren't trying to do that -- you are using Linux, and it needs to be told where to load the program and how to start it.

Usually this info is supplied by the `ELF` file header and program headers (which the linker prepares), although Linux can execute other file formats as well.

> Can I do something to make it run without ld?

Sure. You can supply all the `ELF` header and program header bits *without* involving a linker at all. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22039866/50617). It's just much harder to do correctly, and to debug when things go wrong.

Comment: Clear, concise, and fills in my knowledge gaps precisely! Thanks Employed Russian!